# How to pass several parameters from one view to another (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, parameter-passing

What is the best way to pass these parameters from one jsp page to another?

First handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postSearchStudent(
                    @RequestParam(value = "program.programId") String programId,
                    @RequestParam(value = "rollNumber") String rollNumber,
                    @RequestParam(value = "rollYear") String rollYear,
                    @RequestParam(value = "indexNumber") String indexNumber,
                    Model model) {

    // do something ???

    // Call StudentService to do the searching
    Student student = studentService.search(indexNumber);

    // if student isn't in the db load addStudent.jsp, else load student.jsp
    if (student == null)
        return "addStudent";
    else
        return "student";
}
```

searchStudent.jsp:

```
<c:url var="searchUrl" value="/essays/main/student/search" />
<form:form modelAttribute="student" method="POST" action="${searchUrl}">
```

Second handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAddStudent(
                    @RequestParam(value = "program.programId") String programId,
                    @RequestParam(value = "rollNumber") String rollNumber,
                    @RequestParam(value = "rollYear") String rollYear,
                    @RequestParam(value = "indexNumber") String indexNumber,
                    Model model) {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setRollNumber(rollNumber);
        student.setRollYear(rollYear);
        student.setIndexNumber(indexNumber);
        Program program = programService.get(programId);
        student.setProgram(program);
        model.addAttribute("student", student);

        return "addStudent";
}
```

addStudent.jsp:

```
<c:url var="saveUrl" value="/essays/main/student/add" />
<form:form commandName="student" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
```

Can anyone tell me how to pass these 4 params (programId, rollNumber, rollYear, indexNumber) from searchStudent.jsp to addStudent.jsp?

Comment: The same way you do it in your `getAddStudent()` method ...

Answer (score 1):

Why not save these in cookies? using something like jquery cookie plugin? OR add these parameters as attributes to a model object and pass the model to the view OR look into something like @ ControllerAdvice if you are using Spring 3.2. Plenty of options.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Request Dispatcher. You need to forward the request to the addStudent.jsp.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create a form for this attributes as

***StudentCriteriaForm***

```
public class StudentCriteriaForm {

    private String programId;
    private String rollNumber;
    private String rollYear;
    private String indexNumber;

    //setter && Getter Methods
}
```

now bind this attributes to your jsp as follows

***searchStudent.jsp***

```
<c:url var="searchUrl" value="/essays/main/student/search" />
<form:form modelAttribute="student" method="POST" action="${searchUrl}" commandName="studentCriteriaForm">
    <form:input path="programId" />
    <form:input path="rollNumber" />
    <form:input path="rollYear" />
    <form:input path="indexNumber" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSearch" >
</form:form>
```

***Controller***

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postSearchStudent(@ModelAttribute("studentCriteriaForm") StudentCriteriaForm studentCriteriaForm,
    ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {
    // do something ???
    // Call StudentService to do the searching
    Student student = studentService.search(studentCriteriaForm.getIndexNumber());
    // if student isn't in the db load addStudent.jsp, else load student.jsp
    if (student == null) {
    //here you can pass your parameters to your addStudent.jsp
        model.addAttribute("studentCriteriaForm", studentCriteriaForm);
    return "addStudent";
    } else {
        return "student";
    }   
}
```

now you can get values of this parameters on your ***addStudent.jsp*** page as

```
<c:url var="saveUrl" value="/essays/main/student/add" />
<form:form commandName="student" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
<c:out value="${studentCriteriaForm.programId}"></c:out>
<c:out value="${studentCriteriaForm.rollNumber}"></c:out>
<c:out value="${studentCriteriaForm.rollYear}"></c:out>
<c:out value="${studentCriteriaForm.indexNumber}"></c:out>
```

or you can directly navigate from `postSearchStudent()` method to `getAddStudent()` method also.
hope this will solve your problem.